# Connecting button to input fields without form

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of HTML code:

```
<p>
    <input id='addItemName' name='addItemName' placeholder='Item Name'>
    <input id='addItemValue' name='addItemValue' placeholder='Value'>
    <button id='addItemButton' onclick='addItem()'>Add Item</button>
</p>
```

While this code is not surrounded with `<form>` tag (I don't need it because data entered in `<input>` fields is only handled by JavaScript and not PHP), I would like to provide user a choice: to click a button with their mouse **or** to hit 'Enter' while editing (focusing on) any of these two fields.

I don't need separate event for hitting 'Enter' to be handled by JS. I just want to make 'Enter' hit do the same thing as the button does. And again, no `<form>` because of page refreshing.

Thanks.

**UPD**: Okay, `<form>` is actually OK if `<button type='button'>`, so that's no submitting and thus no refreshing. Still, even if fields and the button are in the same `<form>`, 'Enter' won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try somthing like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id='addItemName' name='addItemName' placeholder='Item Name' onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event)">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function inputKeyUp(e) {
    e.which = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(e.which == 13) {  //Key code of Enter
        addItem();
    }
}
```

Or you can try this:

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="addItem();">
     <input id='addItemName' name='addItemName' placeholder='Item Name'>
     <input id='addItemValue' name='addItemValue' placeholder='Value'>
     <button id='addItemButton'>Add Item</button>
 </form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function addItem(){
      // do your things here
      return false;
 }
```

Working example is on [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/92EFv/)

Comment: I would like not to use JS things to cope with that. I mean, it'd easier to do some HTML trick with those fields and button. But in case there will be no such proper solution, I'll take this one to account. Thanks.

Comment: You can try form tag also. If don't want javascript handler. I have edited the code.

Comment: Oh great, that second way of yours works just great. Thank you! But what is `action="javascript:void(0)"` though?

Comment: Some description of Javascript:void(0) is here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the form tag and then in your submit handler, capture the event and stop it using event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding `keypress`event to the input and check if the enter key was properly pressed

But in my honest opinion using input fields with the form would be the best idea.

Comment: Using `<form>` gives nothing if the button's type is not 'submit'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example that would provide for the enter button event.

http://jsfiddle.net/e4CzL/

```
var element=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode("hello");
element.appendChild(node);

document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].onkeypress=function(e){

if(e.keyCode===13){
 alert("Item will be appended!");
 document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].appendChild(element);
}

else{
 //do nothing   
}

};
```